# Ajax page in href, inside a echo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Trying to get this piece of code to work:

```
echo '<div class="assignsuccess">Success! The report has been assigned to you. <b><a href="javascript:ajaxpage("view.php?callid='.$getcallid.'", "dashwrap");">Press here to view it.</a></b></div>';
```

However when I hover over the link on the site, I can see that it breaks at the first `javascript:ajaxpage(` and I don't understand why. I know it can be tricky to use javascript together with PHP, especially if it's inside the code, but I can't see why this wouldn't work. I've tried to switch `"` with `'` but that's not changing anything.

Comment: like I said; escape your quotes

Comment: That was stupid of me. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<div class="assignsuccess">Success! The report has been assigned to you. <b><a href="javascript:ajaxpage(\'view.php?callid='.$getcallid.'\', \'dashwrap\');">Press here to view it.</a></b></div>';
```

It should render:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('view.php?callid=', 'dashwrap');">
```

Comment: Ah yes, stupid of me to not think of that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @P.Nick you're welcome.

Comment: @P.Nick you mind to mark this as the answer?